# Geoserver Mapfish printing

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, mapfish, gxp

I am using mapfish module to print my map to pdf. It works well for two layers but if I add another layer there is no response from geoserver. Neither there is any error in geoserver log no in apache.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, the problem was Chrome, the output url was dying without any pdf due to XMLHttpRequest but on firefox it works well.